# What is the best way to compose a link with GET parameters using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, get, url-parameters

I want to compose a link with several GET parameters gathered from variables. For example:

```
link.php?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

In JavaScript, if I have variables `var1`, `var2` and `var3` set already to the corresponding values, I know the link can be composed by concatenating strings and the variables as follows:

```
url = "link.php?param1=" + var1 + "&param2=" + var2 + "&param3=" + var3;
```

Is there a cleaner or better way to do this? In jQuery, the AJAX requests function accept a data parameter that can be easily set as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data:{
    param1: var1,
    param2: var2, 
    param3: var3
  }
});
```

Is there a similar way to compose the link but simply store it inside a variable instead of performing an ajax request?

I'm aware of jQuery's `.get()` function, which, as the documentation mentions:

> "Load data from the server using an HTTP GET request."

I don't want this, I just need to compose the link.

Comment: I'm using [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) to do that. It allow you to parse and stringify query string like `queryString.stringify({color: ['taupe', 'chartreuse'], id: '515'});`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var makeFullUrl = function (url, params) {
    return [url, Object.keys(params || {}).map(function (key) {
        return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[key]);
    }).join('&')].join('?');
};
```

that's a function I made a while back (pre ES2015) - call it with the base URL as parameter 1, and an object like

```
{
    param1Name: param1Value,
    param2Name: param2Value
}
```

> Here it is for ES2015, for laffs

```
var makeFullUrl = (url, params) => [url, Object.keys(params || {}).map(key => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[key])).join('&')].join('?');
```